# Is my UNIX command du failing?

Tags: linux, unix, hard-drive, du

I was checking the space occupied in my hard drive, and I saw strange results when executing the **du** command.

Here you have a sample of what I've typed:

```
marcha_r@Risa marcha_r $ du -cksh *
28M      Documents
972K     Downloads
5.7G     Dropbox
14G      Games
42M      Images
6.9G     Music
50M      Screenshots
20K      Test
26G      total
marcha_r@Risa marcha_r $ cd ..
marcha_r@Risa home $ du -cksh *
49G marcha_r
49G total
```

When I'm on my */home* folder and I execute a **du**, it says that I have 49G occupied. But when I go on my */home/marcha_r* folder, **du** says that I only have 26G occupied!
Where are my 23G? Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks!

Comment: i think it's because the  Quotas ? do you use it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 23G are likely in hidden directories directly located under your homedir.
Instead of `du -cksh *`, run `du -cksh .` and they will be taken into account.

Comment: That's it, thanks :) Didn't know I had to write this dot to take into account hidden files!

Comment: . == all of the current directory + hidden files or directories.